# Can DbDataAdapter create DataColumn objects incompatible with WPF binding?

Tags: wpf, firebird

I have a situation in which I query data from a database and fill a DataTable with it. Then Binding the DataTable to an ItemsControl is failing to update properly. The root of the problem seems somehow related to having pulled the data from a Firebird database, but I can't work out how that could possibly matter. Is it possible for an implementation of DbDataAdapter to create DataColumn objects that are incompatible with WPF binding?

Here's more detail. The ItemsControl is simple:

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding COEStudents}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition/><ColumnDefinition/><ColumnDefinition/><ColumnDefinition/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding [Foo]}" Grid.Column="0"/>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding [Foo]}" Grid.Column="1"/>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding [LastName]}" Grid.Column="2"/>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding [LastName]}" Grid.Column="3"/>
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

My Window.DataContext is set to an object with a property like this:

```
public DataView COEStudents { get { return coeStudTable.DefaultView; } }
```

The coeStudTable is populated like this:

```
 FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection conn=new FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection(
    @"dialect=3;charset=NONE;connection lifetime=0;connection timeout=15;pooling=True;packet size=8192;initial catalog=localhost:c:\\Users\\kdonn\\DBs\\NE\\MIS2000.fdb;server type=Default;user id=fubar;password=blah");
 FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter adapter=
    new FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter( "select first 3 LastName from Student", conn);
 adapter.Fill(coeStudTable);
 coeStudTable.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(string));
 foreach (DataRow r in coeStudTable.Rows)
    r["Foo"]=r["LastName"];
```

The ItemsControl shows the three rows of data, four copies of each. When I change the value in Column 0 and tab away, the value in Column 1 shows the changed value as expected. When I change the value in Column 2 and tab away, the value in Column 3 does not change.

[image]

If I switch from Firebird to SQL Server for my data as follows, everything works fine:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter=
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter( "select top 3 LastName from HRRM", 
                                              @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Viewpoint2;Integrated Security=True");
```

This seems to suggest that somehow the FbDataAdapter is creating DataColumn objects that don't play nice with WPF data binding, but how could that be?